# Dismiss a Modal UINavigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` (a) which is the root view controller in a `UINavigationController` (b). The `UINavigationController` is displayed modally (via a `segue`) from another `UIViewController` (c) that is completely separate.

The issue I'm having is that when I try to dismiss the modally displayed vc (a) I get a black screen with nothing being displayed. I would have expected to see (c) displayed though.

What is the correct way that I should be dismissing (a) which lives in (b) so that (c) is correctly visible afterwards?

I have tried the following so far, none of which worked:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
self.navigationController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A controller can only be dismissed by its parent. Here controller (c) will dismiss the presented controller. Use delegate pattern for this purpose. Another nice approach can be found in the link [here](http://jeffreysambells.com/2014/02/19/dismissing-a-modal-view-using-a-storyboard-segue). Later one is a nice approach. You should go with it!

Comment: Thanks - I used the second approach you suggested which seems to resolve the issue.